# DFS Algorithm with large graph too slow

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, graph, depth-first-search

I have the following graph in C#:

```
1,2
2,3
3,1
```

I already flatten out the memberships such that I get the following:

```
1,2
2,3
3,1
1,1
2,1
3,3
2,2
1,3
3,2
```

The memberships starting from 1,1 and onwards are indirect memberships since 1 is related to 1 via 2 and 3 (1 => 2 => 3 => 1) etc etc. (This info will make sense later)

The vertices of the graph are [1, 2, 3] and are stored in a `HashSet<long>`
I have an edge dictionary called adjList that stores strongly connected edges, in a `Dictionary<long, HashSet<long>>` such that:

```
1, [2]
2, [3]
3, [1]
```

I run the following code:

```
Dictionary<long, List<string>> flows = new Dictionary<long, List<string>>();
foreach (long s in verts)
{
    graph.printAllPaths(s);
}
flows = graph.flow;
```

The methods called in the graph class are as follows:

```
    public Dictionary<long, List<string>> flow = new Dictionary<long, List<string>>();
    public Dictionary<long, List<string>> printAllPaths(long s)
    {
        HashSet<long> isVisited = new HashSet<long>();
        List<long> pathList = new List<long>();

        // add source to path[]
        pathList.Add(s);
        // Call recursive utility
        PrintAllPathsUtil(s, isVisited, pathList);
        return flow;
    }

    private void PrintAllPathsUtil(long u, HashSet<long> isVisited, List<long> localPathList)
    {
        isVisited.Add(u);
        if (adjList.ContainsKey(u))
        {
            foreach (long v in adjList[u])
            {
                if (!isVisited.Contains(v) && !localPathList.Contains(v))
                {
                    localPathList.Add(v);

                    long first = localPathList[0];
                    long last = localPathList[localPathList.Count - 1];
                    string currentFlow = string.Join(">", localPathList);
                    if (currentFlow.Contains(">"))
                    {
             if (NestedFlowMain.unqMemId.TryGetKey(NestedFlowMain.CantorPair(first, last), out long key))
                        {
                            if (flow.ContainsKey(key))
                            {
                                flow[key].Add(currentFlow);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                flow.Add(key, new List<string> { currentFlow });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //get cyclic elements as well
                    if (adjList.ContainsKey(last))
                    {
                        if (adjList[last].Contains(first))
                        {
                            localPathList.Add(first);
                            string currentCycleFlow = string.Join(">", localPathList);
                            if (NestedFlowMain.unqMemId.TryGetKey(NestedFlowMain.CantorPair(first, first), out long cycleKey))
                            {
                                if (flow.ContainsKey(cycleKey))
                                {
                                    flow[cycleKey].Add(currentCycleFlow);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    flow.Add(cycleKey, new List<string> { currentCycleFlow });
                                }
                                localPathList.Remove(localPathList[localPathList.Count - 1]);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    PrintAllPathsUtil(v, isVisited, localPathList);

                    localPathList.Remove(v);
                }
            }
        }

        isVisited.Remove(u);
    }
```

The code works for the graph above extremely fast of course, but for very large graphs, the code is extremely slow. So if I have more around 500K vertices, the code is extremely slow. I understand that is because each vertices can have multiple nodes they go to and each of those nodes can further have multiple nodes they go to and so on.

Is there a way to make this more efficient? I read about memoization but not sure how to implement it in this case. Would appreciate any insight.

Thank you.

Comment: There are some slow operations in there that perhaps can be improved (eg searching in a list, which you could avoid by keeping a secondary hashset) but it seems that you are collecting *all paths* in a graph and the number of paths in a graph scales even worse than exponentially with its size (unless the graphs are very sparse or has some other useful structure)

Comment: The slowness is occurring when we search for all paths. For example, some paths are thousands of nodes long (a=>b=>c=>d...=>n)

Is there a way to speed that up by saving a=>b=>c when looking for a=>b=>c=>d?

Comment: How much memory does your program consume? In case the RAM is exhausted and the OS has to use paged memory, the slowness is to be expected.

Comment: I have 32 GB memory. It is using around 24GB of it while running spiking the memory usage to 98%. I have to store flows somewhere tho. And there can be multiple flows/paths for two edges (a,b) = a=>b, a=>c=>b, a=>d=>b etc. so I can't be sure when to remove the (a,b) key from the flow dictionary.

Comment: Finding ALL paths in a large graph is always going to be time consuming.  Are you certain the you *need* to find ALL paths?  In many real world applications, finding the shortest path is sufficient.  If you need only one path and switch to breadth first searching you will see a huge reduction in run time.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell why exactly your code is slow. To find this out you should run some profiling tool to check exactly where the time is spent. My guess is that there is some slow operations in your code, like string operations or something about the "flow", that takes the majority of the time. I do not understand what the code is actually supposed to do, so I cant really tell if you are doing unnecessary work or not.

Of special note is `localPathList.Remove`, If I understand the code you are always removing the last item, but the list does not know that, so need to *check all the items in the list*. Use `localPathList.RemoveAt(localPathList.Count - 1)` instead, or better yet, use [`Stack<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack?view=net-7.0).

I would also be concerned with using recursion for a large graph, especially for DFS. This would risk exhausting the stack, so you might want to use iteration with an explicit stack instead.

But you should be able to do something fairly fast. Take for example a generic iterator:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DepthFirstLoopSafe<T>(T self, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> selector, Maybe<IEqualityComparer<T>> equalityComparer = default)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>();
    var visited = new HashSet<T>(equalityComparer.Else(EqualityComparer<T>.Default));
    stack.Push(self);
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var current = stack.Pop();
        if(!visited.Add(current)) continue;
        yield return current;
        foreach (var child in selector(current))
        {
            if (!visited.Contains(child))
            {
                stack.Push(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and some code to generate a graph for testing:

```
var edgeList = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
var rand = new Random();
int nodeCount = 500000;
var edgesperNode = 100;
for (int i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++)
{
    var list =new List<int>();
    for (int j = 0; j < edgesperNode; j++)
    {
        list.Add(rand.Next(0, nodeCount));
    }

    edgeList[i] = list;
}

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var nodes = Tree.DepthFirstLoopSafe(0, node => edgeList[node]).ToList();
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Time: {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms, found nodes {nodes.Count}");
```

This takes about 1500ms for me to run, and that is probably about what I would expect when using a dictionary for edges. I know this does less things than your code does, but I cannot tell exactly what it is you are doing, so I cannot replicate this. But I hope this should at least show that it is not necessarily the traversal that is the problem, but the processing that limits performance.

If you need more data, like parents or current depth, it should be fairly simple to add this to the iterator. Just change the stack parameter and return value to a tuple, and adjust the rest of the code accordingly. I would expect this to have fairly small performance impact.

Comment: I store strongly connected edges in a Dictionary<key, List<value>>. If the key-value pair is A, [B,C] - it means that A is strongly connected to B and C. A,B,C are also vertices. My code gets the first vertices (A) and looks at it's values ([B,C]). It generates A=>B. Then it checks if B is a Key in the edges Dictionary and it loops through it's values. So if I have B, [E,F]. My code would generate the flow A=>B=>E, and A=>B=>F. Once all values for B are complete, my code goes back to A's original values in the edges dictionary and does the same for C - A=>C=>..
Checking each node is v slow..

Comment: @Raza156 I'm not that familiar with the problem, but looking at wikipedia several of the algorithms seem to maintain one or more stacks containing relevant data. This should be much faster than using a list, since `List<T>.Remove` is `O(n)`.

Comment: The problem is to retrieve all paths from A=>N, via any avenue. 

So if A=>B
B=>C
C=>D
D=>E, F, G
A => E, F, G via B, C, D.

And if you multiply the edges by a thousand, we may have a flow or multiple flows with thousands of vertices through which the first vertices has access to the last vertices.

Comment: @Raza156 If that is the goal you are kind of screwed. Since the number of possible paths will grow very quickly. If the goal is to find the " strongly connected components", then you should use one of the linear time algorithms.

Comment: I already have strongly connected components. Can my above approach be converted into a stack based approach? I actually tried it but I'm not getting all paths. I'll post above.

Comment: @Raza156 The simplest change you should do is to change `localPathList` to a `Stack<T>`, assuming that is how it is used. That should help performance a fair bit.